# What arguments should add function accept for generic set<E> in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a `Set<E>` interface in Java, that will be implemented by another class `mySet<E>` utilising an `arrayList<E>` to store the elements.

I intend to include regular set functions: `add()`, `remove()`, `union()` `intersection()` etc.

What should the type be for my `add()` and `remove()` functions? I have tried using `add(Object E)` and `add(<E>)` but am running into errors.

Comment: should be angle brackets with an E in them after set and mySet and arrayList but cannot get it to display.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: A great resource for this is the existing Java API. Can you e.g. use what [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) does? Of course, you still need to study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ or some other tutorial on this. Basic generics aren't hard at all. Advanced generics can be tricky as hell and it's very hard to get everything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add(E objToAdd);
remove(E objToRemove);
```

[Reference - Generics In Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Answer (score 0):

A `Set<K>` would usually extend [`AbstractSet<K>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) and implement:

```
@Override
public Iterator<K> iterator() {

@Override
public boolean add(K k) {

@Override
public int size() {

@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
```

Comment: Even though you are right, you did not answer the question.

Comment: @Timo - Agreed - and I am tempted to delete but it does answer the title of the question so ATM I will leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we write an implementation of generics type We use the same type notation as that of the interface/class.

```
public interface ISet<E>{
    boolean add(E element);
    boolean remove(E element);
}
```

As per your question as you need to create an implementation of this you can try the below sample code:

```
public class MySet<E> implements ISet<E>{
    private List<E> myInnerList = new ArrayList<E>();

    public boolean add(T element){
        //write you code here for adding the element
        // i.e. myInnerList.add(element);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean remove(T element){
        //write you code here for adding the element
        // i.e. myInnerList.remove(element);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.